# c# how can i call a function which is .cs function in imagebutton htmlgeneric control

Tags: c#, webforms

I want to call a method when i click the imagebutton but I cannot add or call in htmlgenericcontrol.  My code is below:

I tried this code:

```
var duck = objRssItem;
objImage.Click += (s, e) => { WebForm4.amethod(objRssItem); };
```

But it does not work.  I need to send objRssItem.

```
public HtmlGenericControl CreateDIV_OyVerme_Sub_Yildiz(string id, int subId, Rss.Items objRssItem)
{
        HtmlGenericControl objDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        objDiv.ID = strControlName_DivYildiz + id + "_" + subId;

        objDiv.Attributes.Add("class", strClassName_DivYildiz);
        //objDiv.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        ImageButton objImage = new ImageButton();
        objImage.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        //objImage.Src = strImgSrc_yildiz;
       //objImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click);


        objImage.ID = strControlName_ImageYildiz + id +"_" + subId;
        objImage.ImageUrl = strImgSrc_yildiz;
        objImage.OnClientClick = strOnClientClickFunc_yildiz;
       // objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClick","WebForm4.amethod (objRssItem);"); 
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "19px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "20px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "0px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "relative");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "13px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, "6px");
        objImage.Style.Add("float", "left");
        objImage.ToolTip = subId + "/" + 5;
        // calling the method 
       // objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return(GetRssID(objRssItem));");

        var duck = objRssItem;

        objImage.Click += (s, e) => { WebForm4.amethod(objRssItem); };
       //objImage.Click += WebForm4.amethod (objRssItem); 

        objDiv.Controls.Add(objImage);

        return objDiv;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass arguments on adding event-handlers.

I would suggest to use the `ImageButtons`'s [`CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument.aspx) property for this purpose. Note that `RssItem`cannot be used as `CommandArgument` as long as it is not a string since it must be rendered as HTML.

Normally you would use the `ID` (or anything that identifies it). Then you can use it in the event-handler to create an `RssItem` instance if you need it.

```
objImage.CommandArgument = objRssItem.ID;
```